# Libclang parse error

Tags: c++, qt, libclang

I use libclang with qt in order to create auto-complete feature for my custom IDE.

I made this function:

```
QList<CompleterItem> CodeTool::autocompletion(QString content, QTextCursor cursor, QString filepath, QStringList options)
{
    QList<CompleterItem> lst;

    QTemporaryFile file;
    file.open();
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << content;

    const char* filen = file.fileName().toStdString().c_str();

    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);

    const char* args[] = {"-x", "c++" };
    qDebug() << filen;

    CXTranslationUnit tu = NULL;
    CXErrorCode err = clang_parseTranslationUnit2(index, filen, args, 2, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_PrecompiledPreamble | CXTranslationUnit_Incomplete, &tu );
    qDebug() << filen;
    if (err != 0){
        qDebug() << err;
        return lst;
    }

    // some things ....
}
```

But it doesn't work. Output shows error code = 1 (Unknow Error in libclang documentation). Moreover, `filen` is modified before and after calling parse function. 
Example:

> C:/Users/Yoann/AppData/Local/Temp/plugin-test.Ns4152
>
> C:\Dev\Qt\Qt5.5.0\Tools\mingw492_32\include\c++\4.9.2

Thanks,

Comment: The value `1` is definitely "valid", it means `CXError_Failure`. I think you need to COPY the string from `file.filenmae().toStdString().c_str()` [or pass exactly that to the function, so that the compiler knows to keep it around], which explains why it's changing. Once you have the right filename passed in, you should use the `clang_getDiagnistic` and friends to figure out what errors, if any, you get.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by using `parseTranslationUnit` instead of `parseTranslationUnit2`

```
CXTranslationUnit tu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, file.fileName().toStdString().c_str(), args, 3, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_PrecompiledPreamble | CXTranslationUnit_Incomplete);
if (tu == NULL){
  return lst;
}
```